# bash command unexpected EOF while looking for matching

Tags: bash

I want to create a bash file where I connect to a docker container(mysql) and I run a query, and after I want to output the result in a csv file. What I've tried:

```
 #!/bin/bash

 docker-compose exec db /bin/bash -c 'mysql -u user -ppassword dbname 
 -e "SELECT c.id, c.first_name, c.last_name, 
 c.email, cp.id, cp.name, company.id, company.name FROM 
 db.candidate c LEFT JOIN db.candidate_position cp ON 
 cp.id = c.candidate_position_id LEFT JOIN db.company company 
 ON company.id = c.company_id INTO OUTFILE \'Result.csv\'"'
```

The error is that I get:

```
 line 3: unexpected EOF while looking for matching `"'
```

Comment: `\'` does *not* escape `'` within `'…'`.

Comment: but how then to escape it?

Comment: But it's not working if I apply that solution.

Comment: ‘Emulating’ your command with `bash -c 'echo "a  \'b\'"'` gives the same error. Fixing it as per the duplicate with `bash -c 'echo "a  '"'"'b'"'"'"'` solves it and prints `a  'b'` as expected.

Comment: You are running a single command; I don't think you need `bash -c` at all.

Answer (score 1):

You cannot include `'` inside single quotes; you need to change the outer quotes.

```
docker-compose exec db /bin/bash -c "mysql -u user -ppassword dbname 
 -e \"SELECT c.id, c.first_name, c.last_name, 
 c.email, cp.id, cp.name, company.id, company.name FROM 
 db.candidate c LEFT JOIN db.candidate_position cp ON 
 cp.id = c.candidate_position_id LEFT JOIN db.company company 
 ON company.id = c.company_id INTO OUTFILE 'Result.csv'\""
```

However, since you are only running a single command, you don't need the `bash -c`; just run `mysql` directly.

```
docker-compose exec db mysql -u user -ppassword dbname \
   -e "SELECT c.id,
              c.first_name,
              c.last_name, 
              c.email,
              cp.id,
              cp.name,
              company.id,
              company.name
       FROM
         db.candidate c
         LEFT JOIN db.candidate_position cp
            ON cp.id = c.candidate_position_id
         LEFT JOIN db.company company
            ON company.id = c.company_id
       INTO OUTFILE 'Result.csv'
      "
```